# Input type text box not collapsing while window resizing

Tags: html, css

I have given my header section in the below fiddle...I'm not able to give the whole code as its too huge...

But the problem is only with the header...

As I resize the browser window, the input type box stays the same size; I want the width of the input box to change as the width of the viewport changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hJ4t/

html

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 logo"><img src="theme/img/pp_logo_beta_lg.png" width="312" height="36" align="left"></div>
    <!-- move these links to the right-->
    <div class="newmenu">
      <ul>
            <li id="datalink"><a href="#">LIB</a></li>
            <li id="helplink"><a href="./SearchHelp">HELP</a></li>
            <li id="FeedbackLink"><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
            <li id="logoutLink"><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainsearch"><div id="mainsearchbutton" class="searchtitle"> SEARCH:</div><div id="searchbox">
      <input id="small_search_string" name="search_string" type="text" class="newsearch rounded" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500" ><input type="button" id="searchButton1" class="searchButton" title="Click here to search the database" onclick="performSearch();" >

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.rounded {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
}

.newmenu {
    float: right;
    z-index: 3000;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.newmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.newmenu li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause the input to change width.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a38tf/1/) do what you want? It's a little bit unclear from the question. I added the entire search div to the `.newmenu` in the HTML. I then made it an inline-block and added negative margins to counter the list-item margins.

### HTML

```
<div class="newmenu">
   <ul>
     <li id="searchItem">
       <div id="mainsearch">
          <div id="mainsearchbutton" class="searchtitle"> SEARCH:</div>
          <div id="searchbox">
            <input id="small_search_string" name="search_string"
              type="text" class="newsearch rounded" placeholder="Search..."
              maxlength="500" />
            <input type="button" id="searchButton1" class="searchButton"
              title="Click here to search the database"
              onclick="performSearch();" />
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
 <li id="datalink"><a href="#">LIB</a></li>
...
```

### CSS

```
#mainsearch {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:-20px;
  margin-left:-12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few things wrong with your HTML code. Nowadays,`input` and `img` tags should be self closing, like so:

```
<img alt="" src="" />
<input type="" onclick="" />
```

Moving on to your question, I'm actually very unsure about what you're asking. So, I'm answering a possible question about how to make the `input` box automatically change its size in accordance with the page itself resizing: the easiest and fastest way to do so is to specify the width as a percentage. Percentage widths automatically resize each time the container of the element does. For safety precautions and to prevent the `input` box from getting too big or too small, we should use the `min-width` and `max-width` values.

To do this, we would add the following css code to a class used by your `input` box (the class shouldn't be used by anything else):

```
width: 30%
min-width: 50px;
max-width: 200px;
```

I've already tried it out using your code by adding a whole new `css` class and assigning it to the `input` box:

HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 logo">
        <img alt="Prices Paid Portal" src="theme/img/pp_logo_beta_lg.png" width="312" height="36" align="left"/> 
    </div>

    <!-- move these links to the right-->
    <div class="newmenu">
        <ul>
            <li id="datalink"><a href="#">LIB</a></li>
            <li id="helplink"><a href="./SearchHelp">HELP</a></li>
            <li id="FeedbackLink"><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
            <li id="logoutLink"><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainsearch">
        <div id="mainsearchbutton" class="searchtitle"> 
            SEARCH:
        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            <input id="small_search_string" name="search_string" type="text" class="newsearch rounded resizeSearchBar" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500" >
            <input type="button" id="searchButton1" class="searchButton" title="Click here to search the database" onclick="performSearch();" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.resizeSearchBar {
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.rounded {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575e;
}

.newmenu {
    float: right;
    z-index: 3000;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.newmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.newmenu li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Comment: That's what exactly Im looking for..The elements needs to resize when the browser size is minimized..I will try your logic and keep you posted tomo..Thanks

Comment: Alright...as you test my logic, be sure to keep in mind that you can adjust the `min-width` and `max-width` css attributes to whatever you want. I know that may seem obvious, but its always the little things :)